# Block calls for many time ranges in the 24 hours

Tags: calls, automation, call-screening, android-13

I have Xiaomi Poco F3 running on Android 13, fully updated. I know my relative is aging fast in the last few months, so we normally call each other 4 to 7 times a day. TODAY: I visited her at 11:20. At 14:05, she had already called me three times. So, to put down a little stress on me, meanwhile letting her keep her phone, I thought about taking a selective blocking action on that number.

Says my phone refuses her calls:

- from 00:00 to 08:30
- from 09:45 to 12:30
- from 13:30 to 16:30
- from 17:10 to 18:45
- from 23:00 to 00:00

While I may call her anytime, **she will be able to reach me** only on the usual timetable:

- Coffee time 08:30 > 09:45
- Meal time 16:30 > 17:00
- Supper time 18:45 > 23:00

***BUT NOT DURING WORKING HOURS AND NIGHT***. Meanwhile, all the other calls are as per usual

I couldn't find any leads to a practical answer on the web. Only generic-non-useful-well-known.

Comment: Have you considered an automation app such as Tasker, MacroDroid or Automate? I know that Tasker and MacroDroid can easily reject call from a number. You can setup triggers and constraints as time between X and Y hours. Or setup two tasks where one activates call rejection when time is A,B,C hours and the other disables call rejection when time is D,E,F hours.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. While we sympathize with your relative's condition, I'm sorry that some of the info that is irrelevant to solving the issue here got trimmed because it may distract from the main question. Meanwhile, consider trying what Firelord suggested. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Information are added for context.      If was thinking somebodu else got the issue from Kids ( during working hours ) ... and The Boss ( while on hollidays )

Comment: I was thinking someone else got the issue from Kids ( during working hours ) ... and The Boss ( while on holiday)  ---> There is a manual way: on the contact > hamburger dots > "send to mailbox "/"unsend to mailbox" (provided you do not have a mailbox)  So The Caller will get the "Busy" response. Now I'll find a way to automatize and report back

Comment: @firelord
MacroDroid like the other Apps: (1) senses "a call" that you can generically "Block/unblock"--- I didn't find a way to sense "a specific caller" -(2) That Apps cannot interact with "Contact" App to insert or remove "send to mailbox" on a specific name ---->Results NONE - <that are the only to way I've found possible at the moment> Any other suggestions please ?.